# Conditional generic type Property '...' does not exist on type '...'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAIQQGwgQwHYAVMBOmAthMBAVBAB7nYAmAzlAEbpbYB8UAvFAN6t2OAPphCJMhQBcUVHAw58RUuUoBfKADIoACnmK8E1RSq0IDZsAIBXaAH4BUAGYBLAo2BjjUgrOw2xCymmrKCjBAAxnAM3iq%20sp4ErtgA5lDqAJQAsABQedHYnqyEvFAowkbxamZ0TEIKHJy6zgiy8EgGHMqSapyZvNz8eVCjUK7Oeq1wAHRsjaLi1RQDw7ljGy4IM24eXku9FCNjmhBoEQLHm1uzEYX0cYcEVxl56nl5LIS6gvOGjyY-FBrHYADQudyeAEJKAARgATABmDI5fK5IA)

```
type Foo<BooleanParameter extends boolean> = { boolean_parameter: BooleanParameter } & (BooleanParameter extends true ? { first_parameter: number } : { second_parameter: string })

const bar = <BooleanParameter extends boolean>(foo: Foo<BooleanParameter>) => {
    if (foo.boolean_parameter) {
        //foo.first_parameter Property 'first_parameter' does not exist on type 'Foo<BooleanParameter>'.
    } else {
        //foo.second_parameter Property 'second_parameter' does not exist on type 'Foo<BooleanParameter>'.
    }
}
```

Why can't I access `first_parameter` and `second_parameter` when `boolean_parameter` is generic?

Comment: There's no requirement that `foo` be `Foo<true>` or `Foo<false>`. It could be `Foo<boolean>`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m357Aw). Does that explain the issue enough for you or is there something missing?

Comment: No errors appear if I try to inform the function parameter. But my goal is to access the parameters inside the function using the `boolean_parameter` inside the `if` without causing the same errors like in my [example](https://tsplay.dev/wOJkzW) and [yours](https://tsplay.dev/m357Aw)

Comment: It works if you use a discriminated union like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAjBAbCBDAOwH0w8AnPAWwmAjIC4pgyBXCAbigDMBLMgZ2AlyVGnUYEWlDHSgBfKAB80mHPmKkK1Wg255s-DlEMBjOAQAmwrWN2CyPAgHN57ALAAoT2YKDM5ZCgACi4ERng4AEpkAD40TyhEqB4uYNC4ADosOFxCa1EdaNQEpNL0jN4BIU0CuhLEhQgDaGKPUrKEDNNzKxrtOrakuU9hrw8MciD0bNyNEX7dZjYAGm4+QXyFxgBGACYAZnlIz08gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you...

```
type TrueBoolean = { boolean_parameter: true } & { first_parameter: number };
type FalseBoolean = { boolean_parameter: false } & { second_parameter: string };

type Foo<B extends boolean> = B extends true ? TrueBoolean : FalseBoolean;

const bar = <B extends boolean>(foo: Foo<B>) => {
  if (foo.boolean_parameter) {
    return foo.first_parameter;
  } else {
    return foo.second_parameter;
  }
}

const f: Foo<boolean> = { boolean_parameter: true, first_parameter: 20 };
bar(f); // okay

const g: Foo<boolean> = { boolean_parameter: false, second_parameter: "20" };
bar(g); // okay

// const h: Foo<boolean> = { boolean_parameter: true, second_parameter: "3" }; // Error, Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'second_parameter' does not exist in type 'TrueBoolean'
// const i: Foo<boolean> = { boolean_parameter: false, first_parameter: 3 }; // Error, Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'first_parameter' does not exist in type 'FalseBoolean'
```